# c# xor encrypt to javascript decrypt

Tags: javascript, c#, xor

I'm testing a simple encrypt of string from c# and decrypt in javascript using xor.

In C# i encode as follow:

```
private byte[] _Key { get; set; }
private Encoding _Encoding { get; set; }

public XOREncryption(string key) 
{
    _Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    _Key = _Encoding.GetBytes(key).Where(a1 => a1 != 0).ToArray();
}

public string Encrypt(string plain_text)
{
    int i = 0;
    byte[] octets = _Encoding
                    .GetBytes(plain_text)
                    .Select(b => (byte)(b ^ _Key[(++i) % _Key.Length]))
                    .ToArray()
                    ;
    string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(octets);
    return cipherText;
}
```

Using the following:

```
plainText = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
key = "19631280-2e7d-4ffe-8d80-f310c590d37e";
```

Results in:

```
encryptedText = bV5WEUNNWU5ZRVUWQkMIRgNCQERSRUAWVlUQDENcQkRHXwARVVdJSBJcX0oc
```

Now I would like to decrypt this in javascript:

```
function xor_string( str, key ) {
    var xored = "";

    for (i=0; i < str.length;i++) {
        var a = str.charCodeAt(i);
        var b = a ^ key;
        xored = xored + String.fromCharCode(b);
    }

    return xored;
}
```

But its returning the same value.  Example:

```
var key = "19631280-2e7d-4ffe-8d80-f310c590d37e"
var data = "bV5WEUNNWU5ZRVUWQkMIRgNCQERSRUAWVlUQDENcQkRHXwARVVdJSBJcX0oc"

var dd = xor_string(data, key);

Output: bV5WEUNNWU5ZRVUWQkMIRgNCQERSRUAWVlUQDENcQkRHXwARVVdJSBJcX0oc

dd = xor_string(key, data);

Output: 19631280-2e7d-4ffe-8d80-f310c590d37e
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**Update 1**

I may have phrased it incorrectly.

This is the encyrpted data that the c# method Encrypt() returned

```
var data = "bV5WEUNNWU5ZRVUWQkMIRgNCQERSRUAWVlUQDENcQkRHXwARVVdJSBJcX0oc"
```

I would like to use javascript function xor_string to decrypt it back to:

```
var dd = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
```

**Update 2**
Ok I found my problem.  I was misunderstanding what xor is.  Jon Skeet tips made me look into it more.  My problem is my key is a string.  I have to get the integer value of it then use that value to xor the text.

Here is a rough code I did.  Its rough but I wanted to see if I was understanding it.

Here is the C# code:

```
        string plainText = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
        string key = "19631280-2e7d-4ffe-8d80-f310c590d37e";

        int nKey = 0;
        string sKey = "";
        for(var x = 0; x < key.Length; x++)
        {
            nKey += Convert.ToInt32(key[x]);
        }

        string nText = "";
        for (var x = 0; x < plainText.Length; x++)
        {
            int charValue = Convert.ToInt32(plainText[x]);
            charValue ^= nKey;

            nText += char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue);
        }

        nText = nText.Base64Encode();
```

The first for loop gets creates a int value of the key.  Then the second for loop does an xor of the text with the new int key.  Then I convert the xor text to base64.

On the javascript side:

```
data = '4KWP4KWz4KW+4KS74KWq4KWu4KWy4KW44KWw4KS74KW54KWp4KW04KWs4KW14KS74KW94KW04KWj4KS74KWx4KWu4KW24KWr4KW+4KW/4KS74KW04KWt4KW+4KWp4KS74KWv4KWz4KW+4KS74KW34KW64KWh4KWi4KS74KW/4KW04KW84KS1';
key = "19631280-2e7d-4ffe-8d80-f310c590d37e";


function xor_string( str, key ) {
    var xored = "";

    for (i=0; i < str.length;i++) {
        var a = str.charCodeAt(i);
        var b = a ^ key;
        xored = xored + String.fromCharCode(b);
    }

    return xored;
}

function xor_key(key)
{
    var keyVal = 0;
    for(x=0; x < key.length; x++)
    {
        keyVal += key.charCodeAt(x);
    }

    return keyVal;
}

var bdecode = $().base64('decode', data);
var newKey = xor_key(key);
var dd = xor_string(bdecode, newKey);
```

First I base64 decode the data.  Then the first loop recreates the key the second does the xor on the key

And now it works.  I know the fix is rough but I this helped me think it out.
Is there a way on C# to convert the key to its int value without having to loop.
I tried the following:

byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
   int d1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(asciiBytes, 0);
   But this returns a different number then my loop above.  I also tried:

if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
       Array.Reverse(asciiBytes);

but value is still wrong for the key

Comment: You don't appear to be doing any sort of base64-decode in Javascript... Additionally, you appear to be XORing with the *whole* key on each iteration in the Javascript code. It's not even clear to me what that means...

Comment: You can't use UTF8 C#-side. Use `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` or `Encoding.ASCII`

Comment: Using .ascii or iso-8859-1 returns the same xor value

Comment: This is my first crack at it.  Is there a javascript solution that will decrypt it based on my c# encoding method?

Comment: @adviner It isn't a solution, but when you'll have it working, it is a suggested change.

Comment: OK Thanks for the input.  I'm looking into it more and seeing my errors

Answer (score 0):

Two of these things are not like the others:

```
function xor_string( str, key ) {
                     ^^^--^^^
dd = xor_string(key, data);
                ^^^  ^^^^
```

You've reversed the inputs, so you're getting the key back, not the original string.

e.g, you should have:

```
crypted = xor_string(original_data, key);
decrypted = xor_string(crypted, key);
```

Comment: Hopefully I'm understanding what your saying.  I'm not trying to encyrpt on the javascript end.  I'm trying to decrypt the value that was encrypted from the C# method.